# Where is a detailed GUI for file associations?

Tags: gnome, default-programs, mime-type, file-association

I am using Gnome on Ubuntu 18.04.

I just fixed an irritating feature whereby Firefox would open PDFs with PDFShuffler instead of Okular (which Dolphin launches). I fixed it by editing `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`

*(And no, it wasn't becuase Firefox was configured to open PDFs with any application in particular, Firefox was configured to save downloaded PDFs; this behaviour is triggered by opening them from the downloads list, for which Firefox seems to delegate to the mimeinfo cache.)*

What is a GUI interface for this? If I press the "Windows key" to get a search box for applications and start typing "settings", I get this:

[image]

I recall previous versions of Ubuntu (or perhaps it was Kubuntu) had a more detailed section in the settings applet. Where is the equivalent in current Ubuntu?

Comment: This seems more a firefox setting than a system setting. Go to Edit > Preferences > General and in the middle you have "Applications" where you would be able to choose what Firefox does with a PDF content.

Comment: The action for PDF is "Save File". When I open it by clicking the toolbar's downloads icon to produce the list of downloaded files, it opens in PDF Shuffler.